# Errors in approximation for Taylor Series

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

Consider the following function to calculate 2nd order Taylor approximation around x = 1:

$f(x) = e^{−3x^2}$

We have to find the error approximation (for −2 ≤x ≤ 2) for the Taylor series.

I know that we can use Taylor's Formula to calculate the remainder. But how do we find the error for −2 ≤x ≤ 2 ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust I'm following this [tutorial](https://brilliant.org/wiki/taylor-series-error-bounds/#:~:text=The%20Lagrange%20error%20bound%20of%20a%20Taylor%20polynomial,1%29%21%20%28%20x%20%E2%88%92%20a%29%20n%20%2B%201) to calculate the expression of the remainder:

Comment: @YvesDaoust I was not able to find the remainder expression.